# callbackUrl for signIn is not working in nextauth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

My Nav component shows Sign In and Sign Out according to the active session.

I want the signOut button to callback Home Page after signing out which works without any issue.

But my signIn button callback does not take me to the **/activity** page after a successful Sign In. It just takes me to the home page.

Any help is appreciated.

My code is below.

```
'use client'

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Nav = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  return (
    <nav>
      <Link href="/">Home</Link>
      {session ? (
        <>
          <Link href="/activity">Activity</Link>
          <Link href="/profile">Profile</Link>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              signOut({ callbackUrl: '/' })
            }}
          >
            Sign Out
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              signIn({ callbackUrl: '/activity' })
            }}
          >
            Sign In
          </button>
        </>
      )}
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: try to put `<Link href="/activity">Activity</Link>
          <Link href="/profile">Profile</Link>` outside of your session condition.

Comment: I need activity and profile to be displayed only when there's an active session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

signIn takes in 2 arguments. Provider and the callbackUrl.

```
signIn('auth0', { callbackUrl: signInUrl })
```

When I added the provider **auth0**, it started working as intended.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, when I use custom signIn page, default callback is not working properly. But if we use default signIn, callback work well.